# INFLUXDB : SELECT DATA FROM MEASUREMENT ORDERED BY TIME WHERE TIME = MAX(TIME)

Tags: influxdb

I just now started with influx, Need help to get the data sorted by timestamp and the latest data by it.

```
select DB,AREA,sptotal,spfree,pctfree from ORA_SIZE GROUP BY DB order by time ; 

name: ORA_SIZE
tags: DB=DB43B
time                     DB       AREA    sptotal   spfree    pctfree
----                     --       ----   -------    ------    -------
1587919100011225116     DB43B     DATA      442      303        68
1587919100011225116     DB43B     SYSTEM    40       35         87
1587919088732608975     DB43B     DATA      442      303        68
1587919088732608975     DB43B     SYSTEM    40       35         87
```

Here, I want to retrieve only

```
1587919088732608975    DB43B      DATA       442     303    68
1587919088732608975    DB43B      SYSTEM     40      35     87
```

as they are the latest data based on time,

is there any query for this? Please advise.

Thanks,

Comment: It seems like a cheap way to achieve it .. But what about `order by time desc limit 2`  ?

Comment: Could be a way but the data is not static, number of lines changes every time a new tablespace is added to Oracle DB. So can't use limit. Any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Last` Function to get the latest value of any field.

Example :

```
SELECT LAST(DB,AREA,sptotal,spfree,pctfree) FROM ORA_SIZE [WHERE_clause] [GROUP_BY_clause]
```

This query should return your desired data.
You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#last)